# send call to the device like callKit

Tags: android, video, call, apprtcdemo

I am using the AppRTCDemo-master sample for video calling. It is working if both the devices are connected to the room. I want to send a call to the other device if the app is not open also.
Here is the link to the sample App.
            https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo

is there anything like callKit on Ios for android.

Please help me to resolve this Issue..........